# java script alexa skills kit array issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, alexa-skills-kit

This is my javascript Alexa code for programming an Alexa cookbook where users can ask for specific types of meals. I have an array with all the names of the meals and they have properties that are defined in the array; name, diet type and what type of meal it is (lunch or dinner etc). However, when I try to call on a meal that matches the input users give through equating var specificFood/ var mealType/ var diet to the this.event.request.intent.slots.value statement however later when I attempt to match the users' input to a specific recipes properties it says that my variables (specificFood/ mealType/ diet) aren't defined. Why is this?

```
var recipe = [
{Name:'apple pie', Meal: 'dessert', Diet: 'vegetarian'},
{Name: 'rib eye steak', Meal: 'dinner', Diet:'meat'}
];

var handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
     const speechOutput = OPENING_MESSAGE;
     this.response.cardRenderer(SKILL_NAME);
        this.response.speak(speechOutput).listen("I have opened the recipe book, ask me to find you a recipe if you would like!");
        this.emit(':responseReady');
        },
        'InitialIntent':function(){
          this.response.speak("Ok, I am finding you a recipe, is there a specific food you would like a recipe for? If so let me know what food it is, if instead you have no preference please also tell me!").listen();
          this.emit(':responseReady');
        },
        'specificRecipeIntent':function(){
         var specificfood = this.event.request.intent.slots.specificfood.value;
        this.response.speak("Ok, would you like a meat, pescetarian vegetarian, or vegan meal? If you have no preference say so!").listen();
    this.emit(':responseReady');
    },

        'dietaryPreferenceIntent':function(){
            var dietaryPreference = this.event.request.intent.slots.dietaryPreference.value;
            this.response.speak("Sounds good, will this meal be for breakfast, lunch, dinner, dessert or snack? Again if you have no preference let me know!").listen();
           this.emit(':responseReady');
        },
        'mealTimeIntent':function(){
          var mealTime = this.event.request.intent.slots.mealTime.value;
          this.response.speak("Awesome! I am going to go find you a recipe that matches all your requests").listen();
          this.emit(':responseReady');
        },

        'generateRecipeIntent':function(){
         var result = recipe.find(function( recipe ) { return recipe.Name == specificfood, recipe.Diet == dietaryPreference, recipe.Meal == mealTime });
        const speechOutputFinal = "Here is your final recipe " +  result + "  enjoy!";
        this.response.cardRenderer(SKILL_NAME);
        this.response.speak(speechOutputFinal);

        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
```

Comment: See [ask]. Show any error messages as text with an [edit] to the question.

Comment: Because they're defined in other functions. You defined `specificfood` in `specificRecipeIntent`, and you're trying to access it in `generateRecipeIntent`. See scope of variables, if you're not aware of this concept. This might help http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch16.html

Comment: You can try making those variables global. Because of **session**, their values would be retained, and you'll be able to access those values in other intent calls too.

Comment: ok thanks that worked